I have issue with getting the wide and long table to fit into the page layout using {longtblr}
 \begingroup
    \fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{longtblr} [caption = {Baseline characteristics},]{colspec = {XXXXXXXXXXX}, width = 0.85\linewidth, rowhead = 1}
    \label{Paper3:table1_long}
    \hline
                     & Total        & Male         & Year of birth      & Born 1920 – 1939 & Born 1940 – 1959 & Born 1960 – 1979 & Born 1980 – 2000 & Extracardiac malformation & Age at follow-up start (year) & Length of follow-up \\
    
    table content
    
    \end{longtblr}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \endgroup


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Hi Thanks for the tips. I am a complete new user to both Tex and StackExchange. Hopefully someone can help with the issue?

Hi! Do you really need the "Year of birth" column if you already have the born year ranges?

I don’t think that placing a tabular (even less a longtblr with X columns) in an \adjustbox is necessary. It is prone to create suboptimal output from a typographical point of view.

Also, please acknowledge the other comments and extend your code to a full compilable example that starts with \documentclass and ends with \end{document} to make the context clear in which you aim to use this table. Thank you!

Here's an xltabular-based solution.

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltabular} % for 'xltabular' environment
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' and '\Centering' macros
\usepacakage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules ('\toprule', etc)
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % suppress full justification
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X} % ditto

\hyphenation{extra-car-di-ac} % avoid "extrac-ardiac"
\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit scope of next two directives
\tiny % equivalent to "\fontsize{5pt}{6pt}\selectfont"
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} L lc *{8}{C} @{}}

%% headers and footers

\caption{Baseline characteristics} \label{Paper3:table1_long}\\
\toprule
 & Total & Male & Year of birth & Born 1920--1939 & Born 1940--1959 & Born 1960--1979 & Born 1980--2000 & Extracardiac malformation & Age at follow-up start (year) & Length of follow-up \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{11}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
 & Total & Male & Year of birth & Born 1920--1939 & Born 1940--1959 & Born 1960--1979 & Born 1980--2000 & Extracardiac malformation & Age at follow-up start (year) & Length of follow-up \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{11}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(cont'd on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table

Bla bla & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
Ble ble & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
Bli bli & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
 
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}


Proposed solution
Using tabularray internal commands where possible (i.e., label=... instead of \label{...}), using the booktabs package extension for tabularray to make the hrules, and setting a small font size while avoiding adjustbox, here's my take on this. I would recommend to switch to landscape mode when inserting this table into your document as it would look nicer if not as "squished". I've included picture samples of both portrait and landscape to show you what I mean, and to help you decide what you want.
Code
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{extarticle}  % Using a documentclass that provided a range of smaller font sizes

% \usepackage{pdflscape}  % Highly recommend switching to landscape to fit this table more "nicely"
\usepackage[left=1.25cm, right=1.25cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}  % Need small side-margins for this one

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

% \begin{landscape}  % Uncomment this for landscape mode for this table (along with the ending command)
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption={Baseline characteristics},
        label={Paper3:table1_long},
    ]{
        colspec={*{4}{X[0.55,c,m]} *{4}{X[1,c,m]} *{3}{X[1.425,c,m]}},
        width=\linewidth,
        rowhead=2,
        row{1-2}={m},
        cell{1}{1-4,9-11}={r=2}{},
        cell{1}{5}={r=1,c=4}{c},
    }
    \toprule
                    & Total & Male  & Year of birth & Birth year (inclusive)    &               &               &               & Extracardiac malformation & Age at follow-up start (year) & Length of follow-up   \\
    \cmidrule{5-9}
                    &       &       &               & 1920 -- 1939              & 1940 -- 1959  & 1960 -- 1979  & 1980 -- 2000  &                           &                               &                       \\
    \midrule
    table content   & ---   & ---   & ---           & ---                       & ---           & ---           & ---           & ---                       & ---                           & ---                   \\
    table content   & ---   & ---   & ---           & ---                       & ---           & ---           & ---           & ---                       & ---                           & ---                   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
% \end{landscape}  % Uncomment this for landscape more for this table (along with the beginning command)

\end{document}

Images
Portrait

Landscape

